# Action delegate in VB.NET accepts a function lambda expression

Tags: vb.net, lambda, delegates

I have a constructor that takes an Action delegate as argument:

```
Public Class DelegateCommand
    Public Sub New(execute As Action(Of T))
        Me.New(execute, Nothing)
    End Sub
End Command

' This works as expected
Dim executeIsCalled = False
Dim command = New DelegateCommand(Sub() executeIsCalled = True)
command.Execute(Nothing)
Assert.IsTrue(executeIsCalled) ' Pass
```

Action does not have a return value and the MSDN states that I must use a Sub for this purpose ([MSDN Action Delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.100).aspx)).
However this is not true as it is perfectly possible to use a function delegate:

```
Dim executeIsCalled = False    
Dim command = New DelegateCommand(Function() executeIsCalled = True)
command.Execute(Nothing)
Assert.IsTrue(executeIsCalled) ' Fail
```

This compiles fine, however the `executeIsCalled = True` is interpreted as the return statement, leading to the unexpected result that `executeIsCalled` is remains false. 
Interestingly, you can do the following:

```
Dim executeIsCalled = False
Dim command = New DelegateCommand(Function()
                                          executeIsCalled = True
                                          Return False
                                      End Function)
command.Execute(Nothing)
Assert.IsTrue(executeIsCalled) ' Pass
```

How can I prenvent that mistakenly a Function lambda expression is used?

Comment: Give complete code (DelegateCommand class + command instantiating).
+ What is the p parameter used for?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: The second snippet (`Function() executeIsCalled = True`) is a lambda expression whereas the third snippet (`Function () ... End Function`) is a anonymous function which are two different things

Comment: Thank you Alex, I wasnt aware of that

Comment: Nevertheless, I doubt that it is possible to only allow Sub() and disallow Function(). Please take this as a guess since I have no proof for it: The distinction between lambdas with and without return value is only noticable in the VB syntax (Sub(), Function()). In C# you don´t have this distinction it would be in both cases `() => executeIsCalled = true);`. When examine the Action.Method or Function.Method I could not observe any differences. I wrote a little test program and in C# in both cases executeIsCalled = true. It seems that this could only be answered by a .NET uber pro ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not perfectly solve your needs because the compiler won't help you - but at least you will discover the errors in runtime and not wonder why any variables are not set correctly.

You could use a `Delegate` instead of a `Action<>` as constructor argument. Unfortunately, VB.NET will still allow any other devs to pass in `Sub()` and `Function()` lambdas. However, you can check the `ReturnType` in runtime and throw an exception if it is not `Void`.

```
Public Class DelegateCommand
    Public Sub New(execute As [Delegate])

        If (Not execute.Method.ReturnType.Equals(GetType(Void))) Then
            Throw New InvalidOperationException("Cannot use lambdas providing a return value. Use Sub() instead of Function() when using this method in VB.NET!")
        End If

        execute.DynamicInvoke()
    End Sub
End Class
```

`Void` is coming from the C#-world and is mostly unknown by VB.NET-devs. There, it is used to write methods without an return value (VB: Subs) like any other method returning a value (VB: Functions).

```
private void MySub() 
{
    // ...
}

private bool MyFunction()
{
    return true;
}
```